# WebView not rendering correctly, displaying source code instead

Tags: android, webview

I have an app with some Android 4.1/4.2 users reporting that a WebView isn't rendering its contents, but it is showing the source code instead.

The WebView display code is pretty standard, and it is working right for most users.

```
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
        webView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
        webView.setFocusable(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!view.hasFocus()) {
                            view.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.w("TEST", url);
                // The app does some other things here, but are unrelated to que question
                return true;
            }

        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChromeClient());
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(Const.WEB_VIEW_BASE_URL, injectHtmlAndCss(guide.getContent()), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null, null);
    }
```

And here is an example of what is happening for others:

[image: HTML contents are not being rendered at all]

I am completely clueless about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the loadDataWithBaseURL method doesn't work well with Android 4.1/4.2.

I really needed the base url to be changed, because many assets were being referenced with relative routes in my HTML code, so I've injected in the HTML within the `<head>` tag a `<base>` tag. Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
</head>
<body>
<!-- YOUR BODY GOES HERE -->
</body>
</html>
```

And I've loaded the html with loadData instead:

```
webView.loadData(injectHtmlAndCss(guide.getContent()), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8");
```

It worked like a charm. Phew.

Comment: I use your solution and not work for me:
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="%2$s">
    <head>
        <base href = "file:///android_asset/" />
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body class="font_Yekan">
        %1$s
    </body>
    </html>`

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(Const.WEB_VIEW_BASE_URL, injectHtmlAndCss(guide.getContent()), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null, null);
```

with

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(Const.WEB_VIEW_BASE_URL, injectHtmlAndCss(guide.getContent()), "text/html", null, null);
```

then, add statement below,it will works.

```
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, In my case, there was an extra newline before the HTML code, so I think it happened because of HTML[HTML format error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvBbb.png) file format mistake